# Is there a maximum RESPONSE size for a nodejs http request, and how can I increase it?

Tags: node.js, http, express, https, mean-stack

Using the MEAN stack, I have a specific API call that works well locally but fails on the production web server...but only when fetching the largest documents in my MongoDB collection.

I can use `curl` to get a proper response, but from a browser, making API calls to my server on the web, I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Much trial and error has narrowed it down to specific very large documents in the collection. I can artificially remove data from those specific documents -- from anywhere in those documents, making them shorter -- and the request will succeed.

That leads me to think there is a limit on the amount of data that can be in the RESPONSE of a request sent back to a web browser. Is that correct?

Google shows me how to change the limit of a REQUEST to prevent DOS by doing something like this:

```
const exp = express;
exp.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '2mb' }));
```

...but it seems I'm butting up against the limit of the data that can be returned. I really do need all of the data that can be in a RESPONSE, not a REQUEST, so I'm hoping the result limit can be raised in some setting rather than restructuring my collections and making multiple API calls.

Comment: Not sure if I undestand it correctly, but if it works with `curl` it might not be a nodejs issue? The only limiting factor for sending a response is the amount of memory available.

Comment: I can use curl to send a request to my web server and the result contains a specific, very large, MongoDB document in its entirety. In the browser, I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE instead. If I change the size of the document, by reducing the number of items in some of the large arrays it contains, the API call succeeds in the browser. I'm operating under the assumption the size of the document being returned is over some internal limit (maybe in browsers?), since nothing else has changed between tests.

Comment: Ok that’s wierd..Can you show us some code, for example how you are handling the request in your middlewares and sending the response?